# ValidationException when using Table AggregateFunction and ResultTypeQueryable

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using a local Flink 1.6 cluster configured to use the `flink-table` jar
(meaning my program's jar does not include `flink-table`).
With the following code

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeHint;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.operators.DataSource;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.ResultTypeQueryable;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.Table;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.java.BatchTableEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.functions.AggregateFunction;
import org.apache.flink.types.Row;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutionEnvironment execEnv = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        BatchTableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(execEnv);

        tableEnv.registerFunction("enlist", new Enlister());

        DataSource<Tuple2<String, String>> source = execEnv.fromElements(
                new Tuple2<>("a", "1"),
                new Tuple2<>("a", "2"),
                new Tuple2<>("b", "3")
        );

        Table table = tableEnv.fromDataSet(source, "a, b")
                .groupBy("a")
                .select("enlist(a, b)");

        tableEnv.toDataSet(table, Row.class)
                .print();
    }

    public static class Enlister
            extends AggregateFunction<List<String>, ArrayList<String>>
            implements ResultTypeQueryable<List<String>>
    {
        @Override
        public ArrayList<String> createAccumulator() {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public List<String> getValue(ArrayList<String> acc) {
            return acc;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void accumulate(ArrayList<String> acc, String a, String b) {
            acc.add(a + ":" + b);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void merge(ArrayList<String> acc, Iterable<ArrayList<String>> it) {
            for (ArrayList<String> otherAcc : it) {
                acc.addAll(otherAcc);
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void resetAccumulator(ArrayList<String> acc) {
            acc.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public TypeInformation<List<String>> getProducedType() {
            return TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<List<String>>(){});
        }
    }
}
```

I get this weird exception:

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Expression Enlister(List('a, 'b)) failed on input check: Given parameters do not match any signature. 
Actual: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) 
Expected: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

However, if I do *not* implement `ResultTypeQueryable`,
I get the expected output:

```
Starting execution of program
[b:3]
[a:1, a:2]
Program execution finished
Job with JobID 20497bd3efe44fab0092a05a8eb7d9de has finished.
Job Runtime: 270 ms
Accumulator Results: 
- 56e0e5a9466b84ae44431c9c4b7aad71 (java.util.ArrayList) [2 elements]
```

My actual use case seems to require `ResultTypeQueryable`,
because otherwise I get this exception:

```
The return type of function ... could not be determined automatically,
due to type erasure. You can give type information hints by using the
returns(...) method on the result of the transformation call,
or by letting your function implement the 'ResultTypeQueryable' interface
```

Any way I can fix this?

Comment: Hi, I think you might have stumbled upon a bug. Do you though need to extend the `ResultTypeQueryable` ? If so, could you share why? Isn't the `getResultType` of `AggregateFunction` enough for you?

Comment: @DawidWysakowicz If I override `getResultType` only, I get: `The return type of function ... could not be determined automatically, due to type erasure. You can give type information hints by using the returns(...) method on the result of the transformation call, or by letting your function implement the 'ResultTypeQueryable' interface`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the problem in a small program but I couldn't,
it only happens in my larger project.
Unfortunately, overriding `getResultType()` and `getAccumulatorType()` didn't help either,
I got this exception in that case:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TupleTypeInfoBase.getTypeAt(TupleTypeInfoBase.java:199)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.RowTypeInfo.getTypeAt(RowTypeInfo.java:179)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.Keys$ExpressionKeys.isSortKey(Keys.java:444)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.operators.SortPartitionOperator.ensureSortableKey(SortPartitionOperator.java:150)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.operators.SortPartitionOperator.<init>(SortPartitionOperator.java:75)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.sortPartition(DataSet.java:1414)
```

I actually also got that exception even without overriding.
The only thing that worked for me was essentially:

```
String[] fieldNames = new String[] {
        "result"
};
TypeInformation<?>[] types = new TypeInformation[] {
        TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<List<String>>(){})
};

tableEnv.toDataSet(table, Types.ROW(fieldNames, types))...
```

Comment: @twalthr In case this is relevant to you.

Comment: Usually, `tableEnv.toDataSet(table, Row.class)` should be sufficient. If not, this is a bug and should be reported with a little reproducible program.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing `ResultTypeQueryable` is not correct in this case. The exception is misleading. Instead override `getResultType()` and `getAccumulatorType()`. The reason behind this is that generics usually cause problems (due to Java's type erasure) when generating the type information for serializers.